# Problema con la suma de dos números decimales V10.4

Tags: delphi, pascal

El problema es el siguiente, actualmente estoy desarrollando una aplicación de consola la cual sume dos números decimales (Números de tipo double), estos números son recibidos por teclado. Pero al hacer el calculo, me muestra como resultado un numero en exp (creo que así llama ) y no quiero que me aparezca de esa forma. Quiero que sea de esta manera, por ejemplo, si sumamos 2.5 + 3 = 5.5, es decir, que muestro los resultados como la calculadora de Windows 10. La versión que de delphi que estoy utilizando es la 10.4.

***Imagen del programa ejecutándose (Ejemplo):***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí, debería de ser: 2.5 + 4 = 6.5 solamente y si la suma es de números mas grandes, se pone mas confuso.

También me gustaría que me explicaran por que pasa esto en delphi, por que, anteriormente yo he echo este programa en C# y resultado es el correcto, si mucha complicaciones.

***Este es el código fuente:***

```
program Project_Suma;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Math;

// Hacer un programa que lea dos números introducidos
// por el teclado y calcule e imprima la suma de los mismos.

begin
    var
    Num_1, Num_2: double;
    Write('Introdusca un numero: ');
    ReadLn(Num_1);

    Write('Introdusca un numero: ');
    ReadLn(Num_2);

    WriteLn('Resultado: ', Num_1 + Num_2);
    ReadLn;

end.
```

Comment: Bienvenido Musical Text a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Al tratarse de números de punto flotante la salida estándar respeta una notación científica, lo que deberías hacer en estos casos es "formatear" el número, es decir, representar el dato de una forma más adecuada para presentarla al usuario, por ejemplo, mediante [`Format()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.SysUtils.Format)

```
WriteLn('Resultado: ', Format('%.2f', [ Num_1 + Num_2 ]));
```

Comment: Gracias, @patricio Moracho eso era lo que necesitaba. Anteriormente, llegue a utilizar FormatFloat(), pero me redondeaba el resultado de algunos cálculos, así que no me sirvió para que lo quería.